# What's the meaning & role of "a vision in cream silk"here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

She emerged from the bedroom, ***a vision in cream silk.***

—From Cambridge dictionary

What type of phrase is this?? What's its role in the sentence??

Comment: It's an appositive noun phrase, providing additional information/comment to the first part of the sentence, i.e. *She emerged from the bedroom*.

Comment: @Graffito what information & of what?

Comment: One of the definitions of _vision_ is _a person or sight of unusual beauty. -
"madame was a vision in black velvet"_.